# Sorcery gem with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorcery

Now i'm using this code:

**User** has_one **User_extra**

**User** => :username, :email, :crypted_password, :salt, :mobile

**User_extra** => :user_id, :date_birth, :gender, :address

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   authenticates_with_sorcery!
   attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name,
                   :user_extra_attributes

   has_one :user_extra, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_extra

end
```

**user_extra.rb**

```
class UserExtra < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_user_extra
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @user.build_user_extra
  end
```

If you worked with Sorcery gem, you'd probably know that any new attributes should be added to **attr_accessible**, so in my case it's: **user_extra_attributes**, but if I add it, then there appears error: 
`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: date_birth(1i), date_birth(2i), date_birth(3i),` `gender, address`, so, then i added them one by one to attr_accessible like this:

```
attr_accessible :gender, :address ...
```

but it's anyway throwing an error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: date_birth(1i), date_birth(2i), date_birth(3i), gender, address
```

What could be the problem ??

Comment: Which model did you add `attr_accessible :gender, :address, ...` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the attr_accessible :gender, :address, etc. to the UserExtra model

Comment: ahh, i'd to try this out, but didn't tnx